# Can't add front end script file using block.json for a custom block

Tags: block-editor

I've used @wordpress/create-block to create a block in a plugin. I can edit, save, view blocks in the editor from all the files created, but when I try to add a script that will show on the front end, I can't figure out how to enqueue it properly. In block.JSON, these all enqueue properly:

```
"editorScript": "file:./build/index.js",
"editorStyle": "file:./build/index.css",
"style": "file:./build/style-index.css",
```

But when I try and add a front end script as pointed out in the [Block Editor Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-metadata/)

```
"script": "file:./build/script.js"
```

Nothing loads. There is a line on the block editor handbook link above "From a performance perspective, when themes support lazy loading assets, blocks registered with block.json will have their asset enqueuing optimized out of the box." I'm not sure what that 'theme support for lazy loading assets' is referencing, and if this is the issue.

Nothing I do will get script.js to load in back or front end when adding to block.json. I'm probably missing something simple, but am unable to find a working example.

**UPDATE:**
I left out a few key details: I'm loading multiple blocks with one plugin, so I have different build and start scripts in the package.json for each block. I had to add the scripts.js file to the start script in package.json to get it to appear

in my package.json before:

```
"start:scroll-down": "wp-scripts start blocks/scroll-down/src/index.js --output-path=blocks/scroll-down/build/",
"build:scroll-down": "wp-scripts build blocks/scroll-down/src/index.js --output-path=blocks/scroll-down/build/",
```

in my package.json after realizing it was the start/build script:

```
"start:scroll-down": "wp-scripts start blocks/scroll-down/src/index.js blocks/scroll-down/src/script.js --output-path=blocks/scroll-down/build/",
"build:scroll-down": "wp-scripts build blocks/scroll-down/src/index.js blocks/scroll-down/src/script.js --output-path=blocks/scroll-down/build/",
```

This gets it loading, but it's loading on every page, even those without the custom block.

Comment: when you say it doesn't load, do you mean your browser says it hasn't loaded in the error console? Or do you mean you do not see the result you expect from the code inside that file? Or 404? Or PHP notice about finding the file? HTTP 500? Can you be more specific?

Comment: That looks like it should work, assuming `script.js` is in the same build folder as everything else. To rule out the theme, it would be fastest to activate a default theme like Twenty Twenty-One and check whether the JS loads by inspecting the page / viewing the source. If that doesn't cause the script to appear, I would suspect possibly a build process issue that's not building your front-end JS, or maybe it's saving it with a slightly different filename or in a different folder.

Comment: It just wasn't loading anything, the file only has a console log right now for testing, and would not load on both front end or editor. I realized I left out a few details: I'm running a custom start script because I have multiple blocks in this one plugin. I had to add the input to the custom start script in package.json and it shows up, but now the script shows up on every page, even ones without block loaded.

Comment: From my personal experience loading multiple blocks with `block.json` is fraught with potential banana skins. My personal preference is to build out the src files with your multiple blocks - compile them together and enqueue the resulting build file with all your blocks in one place. When there's better support (or at least a clear do & do not) with block.json I'll be there with you.

Comment: @Bysander, I'm following the structure found in this post: https://dev.to/rmorse/how-to-create-a-multiple-block-plugin-for-wordpress-mpm. Each block has it's own folder and block.json, then I add a build and start script in the package.json. It's a bit cumbersome. I'll have 10+ blocks in the plugin at the end, and I end up having to start / stop the build as I jump between blocks. Only thing I could find on structuring multiple blocks. Any suggestions on how to tighten this structure up?

Comment: Well, I'll probably be burnt at the stake on WPSE for this, but I remove my `block.json` altogether as it no longer refers to a single block. My `index.js` file has all the `registerBlockType()` for every new block  and I import each block function from each single `edit.js` and `save.js` file using `import * as editor from './edit';` Each exported function is used against the register function (`edit: editor.blockOneEdit,`) where `blockOneEdit` is exported from the `edit.js` file. You end up having one build process for all blocks and is compiled into a single `build.js` file enqueued in php